# Efficient sparse matrix multiplication special case

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

Suppose that I have a sparse matrix `X` with dimensions `(N*J) x K`.  I want to compute the following sum:

```py
sum_Xi = 0
for i in range(N):
    Xi = X[i*J:(i+1)*J,:]                 # (J x K)
    Xi_sum = Xi.sum(axis=0)               # (1 x K)
    temp = Xi_sum.transpose().dot(Xi_sum) # (K x K)
    sum_Xi += temp
```

That is, my sparse matrix has this "block" structure with `N` blocks of dimension `J x K`.  The end result of this sum is `K x K`.  Obviously, the sum above is very inefficient, but doesn't rely on any intermediate (and potentially large) matrices.

My current approach is the following

```py
V = csr_matrix((np.ones(N*J), (np.repeat(range(N), J), range(N*J))))  # (N x (N*J))
temp = V.dot(X)                                                       # (N x K)  
sum_Xi = temp.transpose().dot(temp).toarray().                        # (K x K)
```

which is significantly faster, but `K <<< N < N*J` so I am not thrilled with having this `V` and `V.dot(X)` sit in memory when the end result is so much smaller.

Any advice?

Thank you in advance!!

**Edit:** making `V` `csr` instead of `csc` is obvious improvement, changing above.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that you're gonna find anything more efficient than your current approach so I'd probably use that. If `VX` isnt 90+% sparse I'd probably turn it into a dense matrix with `temp = V.dot(X).A`; `temp.transpose().dot(temp)` will force a copy (since scipy only does dot products on CSR matrices), but `np.dot(temp.T, temp)` won't and will use the blas SYRK shortcut.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes `VX` is pretty much 100 percent dense, thanks for the tip.

Comment: The other suggestion I have is to use the MKL kernel instead of scipy for the sparse matrix products - it'll multithread and you can multiply directly to a dense array instead of a really inefficient sparse array.